# Loading IE Iframe in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iframe

I've currently got a legacy website which only runs on IE, and we do not have access to the site source / resources to be able to update this.

What we would like to do is to be able to run this site ( Site X ) within a Iframe emulating IE on our main site ( Site Y ), and then interact through it

For example if we clicked a icon on site Y, it would load site X and then click on the relevant buttons using JS to load the order details within that iFrame.

Would this be possible?

If not how might you go about displaying information from this IE system upon clicking a button on a chrome site ( We could use an installed macro application to boot IE up manually etc if really needed, but the above solution would be MUCH preferred  )

Thanks!
Tom

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en

Comment: @mplungjan I'm aware of IE tab, but didn't think you could programatically control it